# Remove grey borders from ttk.Button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

I placed a ttk.Button within a frame, which has a black background. However, the button looks like this:

[image: Grey area around the button widget]

Is there a way to remove that grey area around the button? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the normal tkinter Button not good too for you?

Comment: tkinter.Button is not themed, so it's "Windows 95-like" (ugly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
ttk.Style().configure("RB.TButton", background='black')
ttk_btn = ttk.Button(text="ttk_Sample", style="RB.TButton")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked. I was trying with Style(), but without success.